# Automated installation of Outlook Custom Form

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm developing an Outlook 2013 add-in using VSTO.

The add-in is designed to add functionality to a custom form that I've created in Outlook. It adds a region to the form that displays information to the user. Whilst I can easily deploy the add-in using Click-Once, the installation of the custom form is more difficult.

Users are required to enter the Tools/Options/Advanced and import the Form manually. I understand this is for security reasons, but it's a complicated set of steps in an otherwise simple installation.

Is it possible to automate the installation of this custom form? I realise the user will need to be prompted, but can I do that as part of the Click-Once installation ? I can create a custom MSI if necessary.

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

If you're building an add-in, then you must have used the Form Region designer in VSTO correct?  And you didn't use the Outlook Form Region Designer?  If the former, than you simply need to deploy the registry keys for your form region's manifest, which knows to call the add-in for the UI rather than loading a locally stored .ofs file.

Specifying Form Regions in the Windows Registry
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860990.aspx